# Relations, functions and transformation (circles)

Tags: circles

Circular ripples are formed when a water drop hits the surface of a pond. If one is represented by the equation $x^2 +y^2=4$ and then $3$ seconds later by $x^2+y^2=190$, where the length of measurements are in cm :

A) calculate how fast the ripple is moving outwards.

Comment: What it implies is that, the radius changed from $2 \to \sqrt{190}$ in $3$ second.

Comment: And you probably want to assume that there is no dissipation of energy (no friction)